# Display a popup with "swipable slides" in xamarin.ios?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, popup, storyboard

I have done major refactoring of my app and to help my users align with the new behaviour, when starting my app I want to display a few info slides that the user can read before starting to use the app (with the normal "don't show on startup"-button).

I'm using storyboard and have implemented it as using InstantiateViewController from a programmatically instantiated storyboard and just presenting it as UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover in the calling viewcontroller but it doesn't give me the "popup" effect that I'm after. The popup vc is displayed "over" the calling viewcontroller but the calling view "shrinks" as it goes into the background.

Is there another way to keep the design in storyboard but displaying the uiviewcontroller as an alert dialog or similar to get the more of a popup/popover/alert style?

```
{
    var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("MyStoryboard", null);
    var popup = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("PopupController");
    popup.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover;

    // Present the view controller (in a popover).
    PresentViewController(popup, true, null);
}
```

Comment: do you mean like a splash page?

Comment: No, not quite. The splash page is more letting the user know that the app is starting up. I mean like a short tutorial that the user can either close to skip or read if they are interested in the changes. As it needs 5-6 "slides"/views I don't want to use an alert dialog.

Comment: You can create your  product page in app store so user can know the  new behaviour when they download the latest version  https://developer.apple.com/app-store/product-page/